# Match a text style in an image

Tags: text

I've got some text in the image and I need to match its style. I typed a text I wanted to add in and I was able to match the font and so on. The only thing I couldn't have done was to match the patten of the text. I've added some noise to make it look alike. It looks kind of close but not the same:

[image]

If you zoom in you'll see that PB has got some light green dots and lighter dark hues. How could I transfer that to the RNOV.

Is there soemthing I can do about that? Sample different areas, create a pattern and paint with it?

I tried the clone stamp tool and the healing brush tool but I ended up with a messy inconsistent pattern and painted over the edges of the text. I don't know how to make some area not be affected by it.

PS I'm like a newbie in PS :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track. It just needs some finetuning.

1. Make sure you dont use monocomatic noise
2. Add Layer styles for finetuning. I tried it with: hue/saturation,
   colorize with purple and about 50% fill (and some brightness with curves)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Recreate text and use noise**

As you mentioned, the effect can be achieved using some noise (`Filter > Noise > Add Noise`). I think your best option, since you have already identified the font, is just to re-write all of the text and apply the noise to everything. That way you won't risk having different looking elements.

**Option 2: Clone the sample area (and apply to selection)**

You can also use the Clone Stamp Tool to fill the shapes with a sample taken from the original text. To keep it from overflowing the text, just draw a selection with the shape of the letters first (Ctrl + Clicking a layer will select everything in it).

**Option 3: Create a new pattern**

A third alternative would be to create a pattern of the original texture and save it for reusing it in the new text. In this case you would need to select the area, `Define Pattern`, and then apply the pattern as a `Pattern Overlay` in the `Blending Options` of the letters.

Comment: As I mentioend before. I played around with the noise filter. I couldn't match it. I know I could rewrite all that but there's gotta a way out. A simpler one. It's photoshop! )) There's gotta be some tools to sample only within the areas **PB** and paint  with those samples within only the areas of **RNOV**

Comment: @Dunno Sorry about that. I just edited my answer!

Comment: @Yusela I figured Option 3. Option 2 Could you kinda walk me through it? I don't know how to do that step by step. Oh some general guidelines would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pattern overlay, which can be found in the blending options (if you right-click on the layer). However, in many cases this can cause unexpected results, if the pattern is not flawless.